# Relation of Percy Jackson universe and Rick Riordan imprint

Tags: percy-jackson, rick-riordan

Rick Riordan now has an imprint with Disney-Hyperion for mythology stories like his Percy Jackson books. One already came out - Aruh Shah and the End of Time. Are these books set in the Percy Jackson universe? For example, the Kane chronicles and Magnus Chase books are quite clearly set in the Percy Jackson universe even though they focus on a different mythos; is similar true for Rick Riordan's imprint?

I'm well aware the books in Riordan's imprint are probably also going to be set in modern day U.S., but I'm  asking if they will meet up with Percy Jackson on a street corner, or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## They are not in the same universe.

According to [Rick Riordan himself](http://rickriordan.com/2017/04/rick-riordan-presents/) ...

> I am not writing the books and I don’t tell the authors what to write. This is not like using a ghost writer or ‘assistant writer’ to write my ideas. **These are original stories** generated by the authors – their intellectual property, told their way, with their characters and their sense of humor. **The worlds they create are their own. They are not extensions of Percy Jackson’s world.**